# How to get text of an element in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML:

```
<div id="email_address">abcdefg.text</div>
```

Code:

```
email.FindElementByCssSelector("#email_address").getAttribute("outerHTML");
```

I have tried this however I am unable to get the text `"abcdefg.text"`

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: that would be "innerHTML"

Comment: Use `email.FindElementByCssSelector("#email_address").Text;` Or `email.FindElementByCssSelector("#email_address").getAttribute("innerHTML")`;

Comment: i tried innerHTML and text, but it didnt work

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: email.FindElementByCssSelector("#email_address").getText();
doesn't work?

Comment: @VitaliyMoskalyuk : OP using c# and there is NOT such method `getText()`

Comment: try innerText, or 
driver.FindElement(By...).Text

Comment: As a result of using InnerHTML,Text,there was no value.
When outerHTML was used, <div id="email_address"></div> came out.

Comment: Is the url to the website you are trying to get this text from available?

Comment: https://gmailnator.com/inbox/#copytmp+dvfbu@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems synchronization Issue. Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `ElementIsVisible`()

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
 string emailid = wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("#email_address"))).Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some webpages use javascrip libraries to update the DOM dynamically like Angular or React.  In the past when I have run into this issue I used the attribute `value`.

Try:

```
email.FindElementByCssSelector("#email_address").getAttribute("value");
```